# how to get the value from selected checkbox in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

onh**strong text**:

[image]

When i click checkbox table id based column name shown in the right side using json data

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Please post the code that you have and a clear statement of what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.records = [ { "Id": 1 }, { "Id": 2 }, { "Id": 3 } ];
    $scope.selected = {};
    $scope.ShowSelected = function() {
      $scope.records = $.grep($scope.records, function( record ) {
        return $scope.selected[ record.Id ];
      });
    };      
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="record in records">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected[record.Id]"> {{record.Id}}
            </li>
        </ul>
        <a href="javascript:;" data-ng-click="ShowSelected()">Show Selected</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Hiren but facing few problem can u share plnkr link